# Replacing / Swapping a Java class in Java agent instrumentation

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, agent, javaagents

I've read this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation#loading-a-java-agent) which does the bytecode instrumentation in a "line by line" approach. It's clumsy and bug-prone. I wonder if Javassit supports "replacing" or "swapping" a class with an instrumented class. I see the [redefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-) method but I'm not sure it's used for that purposes, plus I can't find any examples around that.

I appreciate if anyone in SO can give me an example on using `redefineClasses` in `Javassist`

My goal is to use Java instrumentation to extract some meaningful data inside multiple  Java classes and methods, much more than just printing start/end time in those examples. That's why I think "swapping a Java class" approach is more efficient during development.

What do you guys think and recommend?

Comment: `It's clumsy and bug-prone.`. It's bug prone to just replace all the bytecode with a previous, precompiled bytecode.

Comment: So is it still technically possible to swap a class thru java instrumentation?

Comment: Yes, but you can not add or remove methods or fields. (And a new version may add additional methods - which is why most agents modify the bytecode instead of blindly replacing it.) `ClassDefinition` has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassDefinition.html#ClassDefinition-java.lang.Class-byte:A-).

Comment: You are confusing two unrelated things. Javassist is used to get the bytecode here, i.e. the `byte[]` array returned by `cc.toBytecode()`. Regardless of what you use to bring this bytecode to live, the way you’re using Javassist does not change. You can implement a `ClassFileTransformer` as shown in that blog or call `redefineClasses`, it doesn’t matter. In either case, you need the `byte[]` array.

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks for the answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are new to Java instrumentation, I want to elaborate a little more on Johannes' correct comments: I recommend you to not just read the Baeldung article but also some related javadocs.

For example, the Java 8 API documentation for [`Instrumentation.redefineClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-) clearly states the limitations when redefining classes:

> The redefinition may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes. The redefinition must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance. These restrictions maybe be lifted in future versions.

Alas, the restrictions have not been lifted as of Java 17. The same method is described there as follows:

> The supported class file changes are described in [JVM TI RedefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#RedefineClasses).

The document pointed to basically says the same as the Java 8 documentation, only in some more detail:

> The redefinition may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes (unless explicitly prohibited). The redefinition must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, change modifiers, or change inheritance. The redefinition must not change the `NestHost`, `NestMembers`, `Record`, or `PermittedSubclasses` attributes. These restrictions may be lifted in future versions.

Besides, the very same restrictions apply to [`Instrumentation.retransformClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses-java.lang.Class...-), the difference basically being that you do not start from scratch there but use existing class bytes as an input and can chain multiple transformers in order to incrementally instrument your existing class. But even with redefinition, the base line stays the original class, if it was loaded before.

Comment: Please do not speculate, as it might confuse or mislead other readers. Try for yourself and report facts, please.